# Migrating from FreeRadius 2.0 to version 3.0

Tags: freeradius

`I have a working solution based on version 2. Intention to move to a new linux server with FreeRadius 3.0. Unix based users with two different unix user groups, network-admins and readonly. The majority of the configuration done in users file.
The problem is that the version 3.0 based FreeRadius solution only returns an Access_Accept for a valid unix user but without attributes. I suspect there is something different expected in version 3 compared to version 2. Users config:

```
`DEFAULT NAS-IP-Address =~ "172.31.100.", Group == "network-admins", Auth-Type := unix  
    Service-Type = Login-User,
    Idle-Timeout = 900,
    Timetra-Access = both,
    Timetra-Profile = administrative,
    Timetra-Default-Action = permit-all,
    Timetra-Cmd = "configure system security",
    Timetra-Action = permit,
    Timetra-Cmd += "show system security",
    Timetra-Action += permit`
```

I suspect the first line should be changed somehow.
Having one specific user defined directly in the users file works fine:

```
`testadmin  Cleartext-Password := "test123"
Service-Type = Login-User,
    Idle-Timeout = 900,
    Timetra-Access = both,
    Timetra-Profile = administrative,
    Timetra-Default-Action = permit-all,
    Timetra-Cmd = "configure system security",
    Timetra-Action = permit,
    Timetra-Cmd += "show system security",
    Timetra-Action += permit`
```

Any clues or suggestions to make it work very much appreciated.

Tried to modify the matching criteria syntax, for example using Regex but the same results.
Attached a debug output when regex was used for the NAS-IP-Address matching:

```
(1) Received Access-Request Id 77 from 172.31.100.106:64400 to 172.31.100.85:1812 length 72
(1)   User-Name = "david"
(1)   User-Password = "********"
(1)   NAS-IP-Address = 172.31.100.106
(1)   Calling-Station-Id = "172.31.100.84"
(1)   NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
(1) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(1)   authorize {
(1)     policy filter_username {
(1)       if (&User-Name) {
(1)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(1)       if (&User-Name)  {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(1)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(1)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(1)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(1)     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(1)     [preprocess] = ok
(1)     [chap] = noop
(1)     [mschap] = noop
(1)     [digest] = noop
(1) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(1) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "david", looking up realm NULL
(1) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(1)     [suffix] = noop
(1) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(1)     [eap] = noop
(1)     [unix] = updated
(1) files: EXPAND ^172\.31\.100\..+$
(1) files:    --> ^172\.31\.100\..+$
(1) files: EXPAND 172.30.0.
(1) files:    --> 172.30.0.
(1)     [files] = noop
(1)     [expiration] = noop
(1)     [logintime] = noop
(1)     [pap] = updated
(1)   } # authorize = updated
(1) Found Auth-Type = PAP
(1) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(1)   Auth-Type PAP {
(1) pap: Login attempt with password
(1) pap: Comparing with "known-good" Crypt-password
(1) pap: User authenticated successfully
(1)     [pap] = ok
(1)   } # Auth-Type PAP = ok
(1) # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(1)   post-auth {
(1)     if (session-state:User-Name && reply:User-Name && request:User-Name && (reply:User-Name == request:User-Name)) {
(1)     if (session-state:User-Name && reply:User-Name && request:User-Name && (reply:User-Name == request:User-Name))  -> FALSE
(1)     update {
(1)       No attributes updated for RHS &session-state:
(1)     } # update = noop
(1)     [exec] = noop
(1)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(1)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(1)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(1)       else {
(1)         [noop] = noop
(1)       } # else = noop
(1)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(1)     if (EAP-Key-Name && &reply:EAP-Session-Id) {
(1)     if (EAP-Key-Name && &reply:EAP-Session-Id)  -> FALSE
(1)   } # post-auth = noop
(1) Sent Access-Accept Id 77 from 172.31.100.85:1812 to 172.31.100.106:64400 length 20
(1) Finished request´
```